# Is there a way of finding by tag my own questions?

Tags: support, sorting

Thre are very good sorting keys, like voting, views, but I guess there is no sort by tag or even date?. Is there a way to know the questions given a tag or date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of semi-hidden [search options](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=) you can use.  For example, to find all of your posts in a particular tag, search for something like [`user:me [java]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me+%5Bjava%5D)

Comment: So it has a search engine like google, WOW.